# mat-autocomplete search works fine with mock data , wont work when assigning data from the backend service

Tags: javascript, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

mat-autocomplete works great with mock data. when i integrate it with the actual service , It won't populate the dropdown.

my html looks like this

```
     <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input
            matInput
            placeholder="LastName, FirstName"
            aria-label="LastName, FirstName"
            [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            [formControl]="userCtrl"
          />
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option
              (click)="onSelect(user,i)"
              *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers | async; let i = index"
              [value]="user.name"
            >
              <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
              <!-- <small> GUID: {{user.guid}}</small> -->
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
```

component is like below

```
import {Component, Inject, ViewChild, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map, startWith } from "rxjs/operators";
import { UserService } from '../../../shared/services/user/user.service';

  @Component({
    selector: "app-change-user-dialog",
    templateUrl: "./change-user-dialog.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./change-user-dialog.component.scss"]
  })
  
  export class ChangeUserComponent implements OnInit {

  userCtrl: FormControl;
  filteredUsers: any;
  selectedUser = "";

  users = [
    {
      name: "Barrett, David",
      guid: "1213123"
    },
    {
      name: "Barrett, Elizabeth",
      guid: "8437593"
    },
    {
      name: "Barrett, Elizabeth",
      guid: "2o934u124"
    }
  ];

  constructor( public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ChangeUserDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: ChangeUserDialogComponent,
    private userService: UserService ) {
    this.userCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filteredUsers = this.userCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(""),
      map(user => (user.length >= 3 ? this.filterUsers(user) : []))

    );
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    }

     filterUsers(name) {
       this.users.filter((user) => {
       return user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0
       });
    }

  }
```

above component works fine and displays the dropdown with mock data ,

Now, Im trying to get the response back from service and assign it back to this.users and it won't work .

Below is what i tried

```
filterUsers(name: string) {
      var split_str = name.split(",");
      const lastname = split_str[0] ? split_str[0] : "";
      const firstname = split_str[1] ? split_str[1] : "";
      this.userService.getGuidByName(firstname, lastname).subscribe((data) => {
      this.users = data;
      return this.users.filter(
        user => user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0
        );
      });   
    }
```

my service looks like below

```
 public getGuidByName(firstname, lastname): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpService.get('file', `/search?firstname=${firstname}&lastname=${lastname}`)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.httpService.handleError('error'))
    );
  }
```

service response is exactly same as mock data that i am using.

what am i missing ? Any input is appreciated. Thanks.